# Laravel - Set global variable from settings table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to store all my settings from my `settings` table into a global variable, but I'm stucked now(I have no idea what's the next step), this is my actual model and seeder:

model - Settings.php

```
class Setting extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'settings';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'value',
    ];
}
```

seeder - SettingsTableSeeder.php

```
class SettingsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {

        $settings = [
            ['name' => 'title', 'value' => ''],
            ['name' => 'facebook', 'value' => ''],
            ['name' => 'twitter', 'value' => ''],
            ['name' => 'instagram', 'value' => '']
        ];

        foreach($settings as $setting){
            \App\Setting::create($setting);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I store all the data inside the settings table and make then acessible from blade, or any controller or view?

### Edit

---

Now, my question is, how can i update a single or multiple value(s) from a form?

I have set this up:

My route:

```
Route::put('/', ['as' => 'setting.update', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminConfiguracoesController@update']);
```

My Admin\AdminConfiguracoesController:

```
class AdminConfiguracoesController extends AdminBaseController
{
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(SettingRepository $repository){
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function geral()
    {
        return view('admin.pages.admin.configuracoes.geral.index');
    }

    public function social()
    {
        return view('admin.pages.admin.configuracoes.social.index');
    }

    public function analytics()
    {
        return view('admin.pages.admin.configuracoes.analytics.index');
    }

    public function update($id, Factory $cache, Setting $setting)
    {
        $this->repository->findByName($setting);

        $cache->forget('settings');

        return redirect('admin');
    }
}
```

My SettingRepository:

```
class SettingRepository
{
    private $model;

    public function __construct(Setting $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function findByName($name){
        return $this->model->where('name', $name)->update();
    }
}
```

My blade form:

```
{!! Form::model(config('settings'), ['class' => 's-form', 'route' => ['setting.update']]) !!}
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
<div class="s-form-item text">
    <div class="item-title required">Título do artigo</div>
    {!! Form::text('title', null, ['placeholder' => 'Nome do site']) !!}
    @if($errors->has('title'))
        <div class="item-desc">{{ $errors->first('title') }}</div>
    @endif
</div>
<div class="s-form-item s-btn-group s-btns-right">
    <a href="{{ url('admin') }}" class="s-btn cancel">Voltar</a>
    <input class="s-btn" type="submit" value="Atualizar">
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

But things does not work. How can I update the values into the table?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why are you not use config files or env variables?

Comment: perhaps he's trying to make his configuration fluid - can be changed on the fly. btw, you could call any class through blade (although nobody will recommend this) using the complete namespace like, `\App\Settings`. If you want to make all class able to access your model you had to modify the base controller.

Comment: @Curos The admin will be able to change this settings at any time from the admin panel, I need to set by example: the website title, it will be used in all the pages by blade, another example: in any page i can need to use my twitter url, and this url will be set in the settings table... Something like this...Got it?

Comment: What are your overall needs? Maybe you can store these values in Session?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

*See improved answer in Update 2*

I would add a dedicated Service Provider for this. It will read all your settings stored in the database and add them to Laravels config. This way there is only one database request for the settings and you can access the configuration in all controllers and views like this:

```php
config('settings.facebook');
```

**Step 1: Create the Service Provider.**

You can create the Service Provider with artisan:

`php artisan make:provider SettingsServiceProvider`

This will create the file `app/Providers/SettingsServiceProvider.php`.

**Step 2: Add this to the boot-method of the provider you have just created:**

```php
/**
 * Bootstrap the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    // Laravel >= 5.2, use 'lists' instead of 'pluck' for Laravel <= 5.1
    config()->set('settings', \App\Setting::pluck('value', 'name')->all());
}
```

From the Laravel Docs:

> [The boot method] is called after all other service providers have been registered, meaning you have access to all other services that have been registered by the framework.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/providers#the-boot-method

**Step 3: Register the provider in your App.**

Add this line to the `providers` array in `config/app.php`:

```php
App\Providers\SettingsServiceProvider::class,
```

And that's it. Happy coding!

**Update:** I want to add that the boot-method supports dependency injection. So instead of hard coding `\App\Setting`, you could inject a repository / an interface that is bound to the repository, which is great for testing.

**Update 2:** As [Jeemusu mentioned in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34126578/laravel-set-global-variable-from-settings-table/34126882?noredirect=1#comment56002628_34126882), the app will query the database on every request. In order to hinder that, you can cache the settings. There are basically two ways you can do that.

1. Put the data into the cache every time the admin is updating the
   settings.
2. Just remember the settings in the cache for some time and clear the cache every time the admin updates the settings.

To make thinks more fault tolerant, I'd use the second option. Caches can be cleared unintentionally. The first option will fail on fresh installations as long as the admin did not set the settings or you reinstall after a server crash.

For the second option, change the Service Providers boot-method:

```php
/**
 * Bootstrap the application services.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Factory $cache
 * @param \App\Setting                        $settings
 * 
 * @return void
 */
public function boot(Factory $cache, Setting $settings)
{
    $settings = $cache->remember('settings', 60, function() use ($settings)
    {
        // Laravel >= 5.2, use 'lists' instead of 'pluck' for Laravel <= 5.1
        return $settings->pluck('value', 'name')->all();
    });

    config()->set('settings', $settings);
}
```

Now you only have to make the cache forget the settings key after the admin updates the settings:

```php
/**
 * Updates the settings.
 *
 * @param int                                 $id
 * @param \Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Factory $cache
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function update($id, Factory $cache)
{
    // ...

    // When the settings have been updated, clear the cache for the key 'settings':
    $cache->forget('settings');

    // E.g., redirect back to the settings index page with a success flash message
    return redirect()->route('admin.settings.index')
        ->with('updated', true);
}
```

Comment: not a bad idea :).    `config()->set('settings', \App\Setting::lists('value', 'name'));`

Comment: Yep, great idea to use the `lists` method, I'll adjust my answer to that!

Comment: sorry about that, may want to add `->all()` to that `lists()`  .. forgot lists returns a collection now ....    `...lists('value', 'name')->all()`  ... living in L4 and L5 world at the same time :p

Comment: Me too :D Thanks. I also added some info about dependency injection in the boot method.

Comment: This is a great answer. The only downside to this is your making a database query on every request. Ideally, you could just re-generate a config file every time the settings are changed by the admin.

Comment: I updated my answer again and added a caching option. What do you think about this solution?

Comment: Nice... I think i got it, but how can i access it from blade? `{{ confing()->settings('?') }}` does not work

Comment: `{{ config('settings.?') }}`  Just replace `?` with your config variable name, e.g.: `{{ config('settings.facebook') }}`

Comment: @tommy and how can I update the table values? Look at my edit.

Comment: You should open a new question for this. Basically, besides some architectural issues, the problem is that you're not updating any values in the database. So far, the route and view looks fine, but have a look at the controller and the repository and try to understand what's going on there.

Comment: The lists method on the Collection, query builder and Eloquent query builder objects has been renamed to pluck. The method signature remains the same.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0

Comment: Good point. The pluck method used to be deprecated in Laravel 5.1 and has had a signature change from 5.1 to 5.2. I just added a comment and changed the code to using the pluck method instead. See ya using `lists` again in 5.4?! ;D

Comment: Hello, I got a problem with this in case of `migrate:refresh`. The error says that the table does not exists yet. When I comment the `boot()` method, it refresh the database well. How did you handle with this ?

Comment: @JazZ I encountered the same issue. The way I resolved it, mainly for the sake of other developers on my team who would need to run the migration, was to first check if the application is running in the console using if(!App::runningInConsole()) before trying to access $settings. Otherwise I return an empty collection.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid querying the database on each request, you should save the settings to a config file each time they are changed by the admin/user.

```
    // Grab settings from database as a list
    $settings = \App\Setting::lists('value', 'name')->all();

    // Generate and save config file
    $filePath = config_path() . '/settings.php';
    $content = '<?php return ' . var_export($settings, true) . ';';
    File::put($filePath, $content);
```

The above will create a Laraval compatible config file that essentially just returns an array of key => values. The generated file will look something like this.

```
<?php 

return array(
    name => 'value',
    name => 'value',
);
```

Any php file in the `/config` directory will be auto-included by Laravel and the array variables accessible to your application via the `config()` helper:

```
config('settings.variable_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in the database just like you do it normally in Laravel. `\App\Setting::create()`, `\App\Setting::new()` and other methods.

For using the values in blade, you can do `{{\App\Setting::where('name','title')->pluck('value')}}`

And, you can also use scopes for this.

```
class Setting extends Model
{
    public function scopeFor($query, $settingName)
    {
        return $query->where('name', $settingName);
    }
}
```

then you could use `\App\Setting::for('title')->pluck('value')`

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my use case, my answer may not be directly answering OP, but hope answering future developers.

This is tested in Laravel 8 application, but i believe it will work fine from Laravel version 5.5 and up.

In my case, I have a settings table with *key* and *value* fields as you may see in this migration file.

```
<?php

use...;

class CreateSettingsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('key')->unique();
            $table->text('value');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    //...
}
```

I heavily use the values stored in this table in my application, so to gain on performance i store those key/value in a config file, I do that anytime the admin has updated a value in the back office.

For that purpose i use Eloquent model [events](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events), to be more precise I use `saved` event, because the `saving`/`saved` events will dispatch when a model is created or updated.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use...;

class Setting extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    //...

    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::saved(function () {

            $settings           = static::pluck('value', 'key')->toArray();

            $stringify_settings = var_export($settings, true);

            $content            = "<?php return {$stringify_settings};";

            File::put(config_path('app_settings.php'), $content);
        });
    }
}
```

I did one more thing, I added `/config/app_settings.php` to `.gitignore` file.

---

Resources: [Store settings table in a configuration file](https://echebaby.com/blog/2020-12-20-laravel-store-settings-table-in-configuration-file/)