# How to update specific fields in a PUT request?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have a `settings` table where I store things like website title, social network links and other things... I make then all acessible by seting a cache variable.

Now, my question is, how can I update this table? By example... If I have the following blade form:

```html
{!! Form::model(config('settings'), ['class' => 's-form', 'route' => ['setting.update']]) !!}
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
<div class="s-form-item text">
    <div class="item-title required">Nome do site</div>
    {!! Form::text('title', null, ['placeholder' => 'Nome do site']) !!}
</div>
<div class="s-form-item text">
    <div class="item-title required">Descrição do site</div>
    {!! Form::text('desc', null, ['placeholder' => 'Descrição do site']) !!}
</div>
<div class="s-form-item s-btn-group s-btns-right">
    <a href="{{ url('admin') }}" class="s-btn cancel">Voltar</a>
    <input class="s-btn" type="submit" value="Atualizar">
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

In the `PUT` request how can I search in the table by the each name passed and update the table? Here are the another files:

Route

```php
Route::put('/', ['as' => 'setting.update', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminConfiguracoesController@update']);
```

Controller

```php
class AdminConfiguracoesController extends AdminBaseController
{
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(SettingRepository $repository){
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function geral()
    {
        return view('admin.pages.admin.configuracoes.geral.index');
    }

    public function social()
    {
        return view('admin.pages.admin.configuracoes.social.index');
    }

    public function analytics()
    {
        return view('admin.pages.admin.configuracoes.analytics.index');
    }

    public function update($id, Factory $cache, Setting $setting)
    {
        // Update?

        $cache->forget('settings');

        return redirect('admin');
    }
}
```

Repository

```php
class SettingRepository
{
    private $model;

    public function __construct(Setting $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function findByName($name){
        return $this->model->where('name', $name);
    }
}
```

Model

```php
class Setting extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'settings';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['value'];
}
```

ServiceProvider

```php
class SettingsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(Factory $cache, Setting $settings)
    {
        $settings = $cache->remember('settings', 60, function() use ($settings)
        {
            return $settings->lists('value', 'name')->all();
        });

        config()->set('settings', $settings);
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Migration

```php
class CreateSettingsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 100)->unique();
            $table->text('value');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('settings');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, step by step.

First, let's think about what we really want to achieve and look at the implementation in the second step.

Looking at your code, I assume that you want to create an undefined set of views that contain a form for updating certain settings. For the user, the settings seem to be structured in groups, e.g. "General", "Social", "Analytics", but you don't structure your settings in the database like that. Your settings is basically a simple key/value-store without any relation to some settings group.

When updating, you want a single update method that handles all settings, disregarding which form the update request is sent from.

I hope I'm correct with my assumptions, correct me if I'm not.

***Okay cool, but, come on, how do I implement that?***

As always, there are probably a thousand ways you can implement something like this. I've written a sample application in order to explain how I would implement it, and I think it's pretty *Laravelish* (what a word!).

**1. How should my data be stored?**

We already talked about it. We want a basic key/value-store that persists in the database. And because we work with Laravel, let's create a model and a migration for that:

`php artisan make:model Setting --migration`

This will create a model and the appropriate migration. Let's edit the migration to create our key/value columns:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSettingsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('value');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('settings');
    }

}
```

In the Setting model, we have to add the `name` column to the fillable array. I'll explain why we need to below. Basically, we want to use some nice Laravel APIs and therefore we have to make the name-attribute fillable.

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Setting extends Model {

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

}
```

**2. How do I want to access the settings data?**

We discussed this [in your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34126578/laravel-set-global-variable-from-settings-table/34126882), so I won't go into detail about this and I pretend that this code already exists. I'll use a repository in this example, so I will update the `SettingsServiceProvider` during development.

**3. Creating the repositories**

To make the dependencies more loosely coupled, I will create an Interface (Contract in the Laravel world) and bind it to a concrete implementation. I can then use the contract with dependency injection and Laravel will automatically resolve the concrete implementation with the Service Container. Maybe this is overkill for your app, but I love writing testable code, no matter how big my application will be.

`app/Repositories/SettingRepositoryInterface.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

interface SettingRepositoryInterface {

    /**
     * Update a setting or a given set of settings.
     *
     * @param string|array $key
     * @param string       $value
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function update($key, $value);

    /**
     * List all available settings (name => value).
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function lists();

}
```

As you can see, we will use the repository for updating settings and listing our settings in a key/value-array.

The concrete implementation (for Eloquent in this example) looks like this:

`app/Repositories/EloquentSettingRepository.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Setting;

class EloquentSettingRepository implements SettingRepositoryInterface {

    /**
     * @var \App\Setting
     */
    private $settings;

    /**
     * EloquentSettingRepository constructor.
     *
     * @param \App\Setting $settings
     */
    public function __construct(Setting $settings)
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

    /**
     * Update a setting or a given set of settings.
     * If the first parameter is an array, the second parameter will be ignored
     * and the method calls itself recursively over each array item.
     *
     * @param string|array $key
     * @param string       $value
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function update($key, $value = null)
    {
        if (is_array($key))
        {
            foreach ($key as $name => $value)
            {
                $this->update($name, $value);
            }

            return;
        }

        $setting = $this->settings->firstOrNew(['name' => $key]);
        $setting->value = $value;
        $setting->save();
    }

    /**
     * List all available settings (name => value).
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function lists()
    {
        return $this->settings->lists('value', 'name')->all();
    }

}
```

The DocBlocks should pretty much explain how the repository is implemented. In the update method, we make use of the `firstOrNew` method. Thats why we had to update the fillable-array in our model.

Now let's bind the interface to that implementation. In `app/Providers/SettingsServiceProvider.php`, add this to the register-method:

```php
/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(
        \App\Repositories\SettingRepositoryInterface::class,
        \App\Repositories\EloquentSettingRepository::class
    );
}
```

We could have added this to the `AppServiceProvider`, but since we have a dedicated service provider for our settings we will use it for our binding.

Now that we have finished the repository, we can update the existing code in the boot-method of our `SettingsServiceProvider` so that it uses the repository instead of hardcoding `App\Setting`.

```php
/**
 * Bootstrap the application services.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Factory          $cache
 * @param \App\Repositories\SettingRepositoryInterface $settings
 */
public function boot(Factory $cache, SettingRepositoryInterface $settings)
{
    $settings = $cache->remember('settings', 60, function() use ($settings)
    {
        return $settings->lists();
    });

    config()->set('settings', $settings);
}
```

**4. Routes and controller**

In this simple example, the homepage will show a form to update some settings. Making a PUT/PATCH-request on the same route will trigger the update method:

```php
<?php

get('/', ['as' => 'settings.index',  'uses' => 'Admin\SettingsController@index']);
put('/', ['as' => 'settings.update', 'uses' => 'Admin\SettingsController@update']);
```

The index-method of our controller will return a view that contains the form. I've commented the update method throughout to explain what each line does:

`app/Http/Controllers/Admin/SettingsController.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Factory;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Repositories\SettingRepositoryInterface;

class SettingsController extends AdminBaseController {

    /**
     * @var \App\Repositories\SettingRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $settings;

    /**
     * SettingsController constructor.
     *
     * @param \App\Repositories\SettingRepositoryInterface $settings
     */
    public function __construct(SettingRepositoryInterface $settings)
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

    /**
     * Shows the setting edit form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('settings.index');
    }

    /**
     * Update the settings passed in the request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request            $request
     * @param \Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Factory $cache
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Factory $cache)
    {
        // This will get all settings as a key/value array from the request.
        $settings = $request->except('_method', '_token');

        // Call the update method on the repository.
        $this->settings->update($settings);

        // Clear the cache.
        $cache->forget('settings');

        // Redirect to some page.
        return redirect()->route('settings.index')
            ->with('updated', true);
    }

}
```

Note the first statement in the update method. It will fetch all POST-data from the request, except the method and CSRF token. `$settings` is now an associative array with your settings sent by the form.

**5. And last, the views**

Sorry for the Bootstrap classes, but i wanted to style my example app real quick :-)

I guess that the HTML is pretty self-explanatory:

`resources/views/settings/index.blade.php`:

```php
@extends('layout')

@section('content')

    <h1>Settings example</h1>

    @if(Session::has('updated'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            Your settings have been updated!
        </div>
    @endif

    <form action="{!! route('settings.update') !!}" method="post">

        {!! method_field('put') !!}
        {!! csrf_field() !!}

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="{{ config('settings.title', 'Application Title') }}">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Facebook">Facebook</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="facebook" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook URL" value="{{ config('settings.facebook', 'Facebook URL') }}">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="twitter">Twitter</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="twitter" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter URL" value="{{ config('settings.twitter', 'Twitter URL') }}">
        </div>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update settings">

    </form>

@stop
```

As you can see, when I try to get a value from the config, I also give it a default value, just in case it has not been set yet.

You can now create different forms for different setting groups. The form action should always be the `settings.update` route.

---

When I run the app, I can see the form with the default values:

[image: No settings stored in the database.]

When I type some values, hit the update button and Laravel redirects me to the form again, I can see a success message and my settings that now persist in the database.

[image: Settings stored]

Comment: You got it! Why do you make things so simple? And I understand what you do! If possible, can you add me on skype? Skype: caiokwsk

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the `Request` class. Lets update the `title`:

```php
// Injecting Illuminate\Http\Request object

public function update(Request $request, $id, Factory $cache, Setting $setting)
{
    $newTitle = $request->get('title');
    $cache->forget('settings');

    return redirect('admin');
}
```

To change the value in db, then could do:

```php
$titleSetting = App\Setting::where('name', 'title')->first();
$titleSetting->value = $newTitle;
$titleSetting->save();
```

The whole code looks like:

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $newTitle = $request->get('title');
    \Cache::forget('settings');

    $titleSetting = App\Setting::where('name', 'title')->first();
    $titleSetting->value = $newTitle;
    $titleSetting->save();

    return redirect('admin');
}
```

Comment: Nop, `Argument 3 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminConfiguracoesController::update() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Factory, instance of App\Setting given`

Comment: Nop what? Looks like you are forgeting including imports/contracts. Please, see the updated answer.

Comment: It's not updating the table, still keep the same values