# Laravel Settings Service Provider Database Migration

Tags: mysql, laravel

I created the settings table via a migration and implemented a SettingsServiceProvider (based on this post [Laravel - Set global variable from settings table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34126578/laravel-set-global-variable-from-settings-table/40794825)). Now it says that the base table can't be found. Of course not, because I need to run the migration first.

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.settings' doesn't exist (SQL : select value, name from settings)

Any ideas what to do? I course I could create the table manually but this would destruct the ideas of migrations...

Any help would be appreciated. I'm using Laravel 5.3.

**Update 25/11/2016 - added code snippets**

Service Provider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class SettingsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        config()->set('settings', \App\Setting::pluck('value', 'name')->all());
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSettingsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('value');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('settings');
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the Model and migration code snippets here .Please check if the table name that you gave in your Model and the one in your migration file and in your database is exact to each character. Moreover try `php artisan cache:clear` and restart apache.

Comment: Could you show your service provider. Without seeing your code I couldn't say for certain but I would imagine that you'll need to add a check to see if the table exists and if not either run the migration, throw an exception or just ignore the issue.

Comment: I've updated the post with both, the service provider and the migration. @AbrarShariarGalib, `php artisan cache:clear` returns the same error message

Comment: @RossWilson, your hint finally helped me. I've added a validation `if (Schema::hasTable('settings')) {` to the Service Provider.