# How to use database table value as constant in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, config, constants, laravel-5.4

There is a table call settings in my MySQL database.
[image]

I want to use **setting_value** as constants for whole project.
How can I do that.

Comment: Elaborate Question...

Comment: So go for it: get the setting_value from your db and make it a global constant in your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34126578/laravel-set-global-variable-from-settings-table  this will be a good answer, I used that

Answer (score 4):

try something like this...
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/providers#the-boot-method

```
// app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
public function boot(){
    $setting = DB::table('settings')->select('setting_name', 'setting_value')->get()->toArray();
    foreach($setting as $set) {
       Config::set('settings.' . $setting['setting_name'] , $setting['setting_value']);
    }
}
```